# Scaling an image in a div to also fit text

Tags: html, css

Right now I've got a webapp working, which I'm trying to add icons to, along with text to describe those icons. I'm trying to scale the icons down to fit in the div, which works great, but also to scale the image to hold text within the div. The issue I'm having is that although the image will scale to fit in the div, it won't scale enough to also allow text in the div.

My HTML code is

```
<div class="ui-grid-b" id="dashGrid">
    <div class="ui-block-a changerbutton" style="height:60px;border-bottom: 1px solid;border-right: 1px solid;display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
        <center>
            <div>
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Smiley.svg" class="windowscale-height">
            </div>
            <h4 class="gotobutton" goto="#formSelect" data-icon="grid">Forms</h4>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="height:22%"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c changerbutton" style="height:90px;border-bottom: 1px solid;border-left: 1px solid;display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
        <center>
            <div>
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Smiley.svg" class="windowscale-height">
            </div>
            <h4 class="gotobutton" goto="#entries" data-icon="info">Entries</h4>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="height:22%"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="height:22%"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c" style="height:22%"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-a changerbutton" style="height:22%;border-top: 1px solid;border-right: 1px solid;display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
        <center>
            <h4 class="gotobutton" goto="#mapScreen" data-icon="star">Map</h4>
            <div>
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Smiley.svg" class="windowscale-height">
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="height:22%"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c changerbutton" style="height:22%;border-top: 1px solid;border-left: 1px solid;display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
        <center>
            <h4 class="gotobutton" goto="#locSettings" data-icon="gear">Settings</h4>
            <div>
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Smiley.svg" class="windowscale-height">
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

, and the relevant CSS is

```css
.windowscale-height
{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 1%;
    min-height: 1%;
}
```

I've got a JSFiddle that shows the issue, http://jsfiddle.net/jDDmC/.

Ideally, the text, as well as the image, would both fit into the outlined boxes.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) Remove the `<center>` tag since it's been deprecated. Use `text-align: center` in your css, instead.

2) Your divs have a specific `height`, and because of that, the text goes out of the box. So in the inline css, remove the `height` property.

3) Finally, consider using only an external stylesheet (instead of inline css), since it's easier to maintain and reuse.

Please take a look at:
http://jsfiddle.net/jDDmC/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like [Fluid Images](http://alistapart.com/article/fluid-images) ?